# SSIS Script Task : How to log to output using Dts.Log

Tags: logging, ssis, script-task

I searched a lot for this but no luck.

I have a script task and inside that I've written some C# code. I have a look and I want to print output like what we see in `Output Window`

I'm using Dts.Log() using below code:

```
Dts.Log("List of files are loaded: ", 0, new byte[0]);
```

But I don't see anything in output window.

I already have enabled logging as you see:

[image: SSIS Log Configuration]

I know if I use

```
Dts.Events.FireInformation
```

It does the job, but I like to know how I can use `Dts.Log()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

A very old question, but it may be worth answering anyway.

When you use `Dts.Log`, it doesn't go to the output screen but to the log window. So you should open the SSIS menu and select the "Log Events" entry.

If your SSIS menu is missing that option, try clicking on the control flow window or the Script Task node.

More info in [How to check the SSIS package job results after it has completed its execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122773/how-to-check-the-ssis-package-job-results-after-it-has-completed-its-execution).